# Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

i am currently trying to get some tests to work... but it keeps failing.

Attached is the error messages:

```
User pages edit with valid information                                                                                              
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name                                                                           
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:                                                                                                          
       Unable to find field "Name"                                                                                                       
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:196:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Attached is my user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before(:each) do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_title('All users') }
    it { should have_content('All users') }

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "delete links" do

      it { should_not have_link('delete') }

      describe "as an admin user" do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
        it "should be able to delete another user" do
          expect do
            click_link('delete', match: :first)
          end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end
        it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
    let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }

    describe "microposts" do
      it { should have_content(m1.content) }
      it { should have_content(m2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
    end

    describe "follow/unfollow buttons" do
      let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "following a user" do
        before { visit user_path(other_user) }

        it "should increment the followed user count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Follow"
          end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "should increment the other user's followers count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Follow"
          end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "toggling the button" do
          before { click_button "Follow" }
          it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='Unfollow']") }
        end
      end

      describe "unfollowing a user" do
        before do
          user.follow!(other_user)
          visit user_path(other_user)
        end

        it "should decrement the followed user count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Unfollow"
          end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(-1)
        end

        it "should decrement the other user's followers count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Unfollow"
          end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(-1)
        end

        describe "toggling the button" do
          before { click_button "Unfollow" }
          it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='Follow']") }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_title('Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end

    describe "forbidden attributes" do
      let(:params) do
        { user: { admin: true, password: user.password,
                  password_confirmation: user.password } }
      end
      before do
        sign_in user, no_capybara: true
        patch user_path(user), params
      end
      specify { expect(user.reload).not_to be_admin }
    end
  end

  describe "following/followers" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { user.follow!(other_user) }

    describe "followed users" do
      before do
        sign_in user
        visit following_user_path(user)
      end

      it { should have_title(full_title('Following')) }
      it { should have_selector('h3', text: 'Following') }
      it { should have_link(other_user.name, href: user_path(other_user)) }
    end

    describe "followers" do
      before do
        sign_in other_user
        visit followers_user_path(other_user)
      end

      it { should have_title(full_title('Followers')) }
      it { should have_selector('h3', text: 'Followers') }
      it { should have_link(user.name, href: user_path(user)) }
    end
  end
end
```

Currently there is 10 tests out of 46 which failed, out of which 6 has the same error. 
Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing user sign-in. Without signing in first, attempting to visit the Edit page redirects you to the Sign-In page, which has no "Name" field.

```
describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    sign_in user    # add this line
    visit edit_user_path(user)
  end
  .
  .
end
```